# Submenu causes issue in defined blog page

Tags: sub-menu

I've inherited a WordPress project with a heavily customised theme. Currently have an issue when viewing the blog when there are no current post entries. Within the theme code, there is an include to a file named submenu.php which will give a customised menu according to the page child that you are on (like this question illustrates https://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-get-top-level-parent-pages/). This is a global throughout the theme and is called on all pages. If no parents are found, it just does not display a submenu.

My issue is that it conflicts with the defined blogroll page and throws up

> "Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in {file location} on
>   line 31

The offending code is thus:

```
/**
 * Get the top level page in the tree for the current page
 **/
function get_top_level_page() {
  global $post;

  $parent = array_reverse(get_post_ancestors($post->ID));
  $first_parent;

  if (!empty($parent)) {
      $first_parent = get_page($parent[0]);
      // echo '1'. $first_parent->post_name;
  } else if (get_post_type() == 'page') {
      $first_parent = $post;
      // echo '2'. $first_parent->post_name;
  } else {
    // If we're in a custom post type build from the slug page
    $post_type = get_post_type_object(get_post_type());
    $slug = $post_type->rewrite;

    $slugPages = explode('/', $slug['slug']);
    $first_parent = get_page_by_path($slugPages[0]);
    $last_page = get_page_by_path($slug['slug']);

    if (is_home() && get_option('page_for_posts')) {
      $first_parent = get_page( get_option('page_for_posts'));
    }
  }
  return $first_parent;
}
```

From what I can gather, it cannot find a value for `$parent = array_reverse(get_post_ancestors($post->ID));`

Also the heuristic defaults to the "else" option and then looks for the parent. I have put in some extra code to detect if $parent is empty - that appears to work and avoid the else statement.

However there are other areas where the parent values come up and I think it's best that the blog page does not even call the submenu.php script. Where should I go looking to find what sets the template for the blog page? I have a feeling that I could block the submenu.php script from loading, I should not even have this issue.